# Почему чудо — юдо?

Tags: этимология

Почему у Ершова "рыба-кит" - чудо-юдо? Это просто игра слов, вроде "павлин-мавлин", или в этом слове есть какой-то смысл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересно, что это за "многие ученые"? Даст Бог, не Чудинов со товарищи. 
Хотя в лучшем случае они путают "древнеиндийский" с праиндоевропейским, но боюсь, тут дагноз похуже.

Вот на вскяй случай из Фасмера.

WORD: ю́до 
GENERAL: -- только в сочетании чу́до-ю́до богатыри́, чу́до-ю́до рыба-кит, чу́до-ю́до маха́нная губа́ -- сказочное и бранное -- о татарине (Даль), также чу́до-ю́до -- в качестве названия морского царя, в сказках. По-видимому, это всего лишь рифмованное образование по образцу слова чу́до. Недостоверно родство с болг. ю́да "русалка, волшебница", которое сближали с польск. judzić "раздражать, травить, подстрекать", лит. judùs "подвижный", judė́ti, judù "двигаться", jaudà "искушение", jáudinti "волновать, искушать", др.-инд. ud-yōdhati "вскакивает в гневе", yúdhyatē "сражается", лат. iubeō, -ērе "велеть" (см. Горяев, Доп. I, 56; Младенов 699, последний -- без русск. слова). Для древнего исконного слова было бы необъяснимо наличие начального ю-. Маловероятно происхождение юда из имени Иуда Искариот, вопреки Афанасьеву (у Ильинского, Сб. Милетич 467 и сл.). Совершенно абсурдно произведение выражения чудо-юдо из герм. этнонимов Теutоnеs и Juthungi, вопреки Бубриху (Яз. и Литер. I, 89); см. Ильинский, там же, 427 и сл.
PAGES: 4,528

Мысль о невозможности начального Ю в исконных словах тем более справедлива и для "древнеиндийской" версии, долго пересказывать, но это закономерность проверенная и подтверждённая теорией. А заимствований из "древнееиндийского" на историческом этапе я что-то не припоминаю.

Всё-таки я за версию фонетической редупликации ("игры слов", как назвал топикстартер).

Answer (score 1):

Чудо-Юдо славянских народных сказок — дракон страшный, многоглавый, могучий.  «Вообще, слово „чудо",— пишет исследователь и знаток русского фольклора А.Н.Афанасьев в книге „Поэтические воззрения славян на природу", изданной в 1866 году, — в старину означало великана» . Имя же «Юдо», как считают многие ученые, восходит к древнеиндийскому слову «йадас» — водяное животное. Действительно, Чудо-Юдо связан с водной стихией. Появляется Чудо-Юдо всегда из воды.